# This is about the ref and initialization in Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I wrote the code to manage a BannerAd like the one below.

However, in this case, I'm encountering an error in the part where if (!ref.read(userDataProvider).userType.isPremium) { is located.

`Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field '_element@103511' has not been initialized.`

[banner_ad_notifier.dart]

```dart
// Package imports:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:pin_share/constant/constant.dart';
// Project imports:
import 'package:pin_share/riverpod/banner/banner.dart';
import 'package:pin_share/riverpod/user/user.dart';

final mapBannerAdProvider =
    NotifierProvider<BannerAdNotifier, BannerAdState>(() {
  final bannerAdProvider = BannerAdNotifier()..loadBanner();
  return bannerAdProvider;
});

class BannerAdNotifier extends Notifier<BannerAdState> {
  @override
  BannerAdState build() {
    return const BannerAdState(bannerAd: null);
  }

  Future<void> loadBanner() async {
    if (!ref.read(userDataProvider).userType.isPremium) {
      await BannerAd(
        adUnitId: bannerAdUnitId,
        request: const AdRequest(),
        size: AdSize.banner,
        listener: BannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            state = state.copyWith(bannerAd: ad as BannerAd);
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
            ad.dispose();
          },
        ),
      ).load();
    }
  }
}
```

[user_data_provider.dart]

```
final userDataProvider = NotifierProvider<UserDataNotifier, UserDataState>(() {
  return UserDataNotifier();
});

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have debugged and confirmed that initialization has been done. However, an error is still occurring. How can I improve this error related to the failed initialization?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to use `AsyncNotifier` to wait for the `loadBanner()` call to complete. Then:

```dart
  @override
  FutureOr<BannerAdState> build() async {
    await loadBanner();
    return const BannerAdState(bannerAd: null);
  }
```

In the widget, this will also need to be handled differently:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final asyncBannerAdState = ref.watch(mapBannerAdProvider);

    return asyncBannerAdState.when(
      data: (state) => ...,
      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      error: (err, stack) => Text('Error: $err'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: No, that response isn't an answer. The advice provided is about the implementation of the BannerAd itself. It doesn't seem to address my question.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I'm asking about the error that's being thrown in the code before loading the BannerAd, specifically in the part where if (!ref.read(userDataProvider).userType.isPremium) is mentioned.

Comment: So either `userType` or `isPremium` was not initialized due to a similar error with asynchronous data loading. Try to wait for your asynchronous operations to complete in the code that is responsible for assigning values ​​to these two variables